# Downloading Chatter files and its comment file in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anyone tell me how to download the chatter file and it's comments file in viusalforce page ?
Like in my dev org the chatter feed type is :contentPost and its comment       type is :content post.

I need to download the all the files in my chatter feed and comment.

For that How can we implement?
please some suggestion to implement.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Comment: I think you can use Data Loader to export data from Feed Item object.

Comment: @sfdcDeveloper : I want to download all the chatter feeds as well as chatter files in visualforce

Comment: We cant export the data from FeedItem